# Missing a page in a journal paper, is it normal?

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

My question comes from the paper [Propagation of chaos for Burgers' equation](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPA_1983__39_1_85_0.pdf) published at Annals of the IHP Theoretical Physics, Tome 39 (1983) no. 1, pp. 85-97. However, the page 95 is clearly missing. It seems that only this version is available online (I have searched via google and google scholar), may I know is it normal for a journal with good reputation to publish paper with a missing page? More importantly, how would I find the complete version of this old paper?

Comment: Huh, it isn't simply not there, but it appears to contain only 1 line of page 14. In either case, this type of error is not uncommon, and likely occured during scanning of the older print copy, rather than in the original printed work.

Comment: @pax In that case how would one find the "complete" version of the paper? Since this is the only version I can find online...

Comment: Try to locate a paper copy near you or use an interlibrary loan.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I am sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean...

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear. University libraries still store printed journals. Check the online catalogue of your nearest and most convenient university library: Do they have that printed journal issue?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen thank you! It now makes your suggestion more clear